# C++ сборка проекта проваливается MinGW NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

Я использую windows XP и пытаюсь запустить проект в NetBeans 8.1, используя MinGW. Проект хорошо компилируется, но не собирается. Получаю такие логи:

```
cd 'C:\CppApplication_2\CppApplication_2'
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/CppApplication_2/CppApplication_2'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/CppApplication_2/CppApplication_2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/cppapplication_2 build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/CppApplication_2/CppApplication_2'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/CppApplication_2/CppApplication_2'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 13s)
```

Понятия не имею, что тут происходит. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Либа pthread стоит?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов как это проверить?

Comment: @AlexandrGnatyuk на винде сложновато... В общем, нужно собрать libpthread и указать линкеру каталог, где будет лежать результат. Проблема, собственно, описана этой строкой "cannot find -lpthread"

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов. А как её собрать? Можно подробнее, а то я ни с одной IDE не знаком на должном уровне.

Comment: @Abyx я до этого уже пытался использовать MinGW, поставляемый в комплекте с code::blocks, и там вроде есть заголовочные файлы pthread.h и libwinpthread-1.dll. Результат вроде такой же был.

Comment: Скачал pthread с помощью менеджера установки MinGW, сборка выполняется успешно.

Answer (score 1):

При сборке не видно где лежит файл библиотеки

```
...cannot find -lpthread
```

Следовательно Вам следует всего-лишь добавить в опции компилятора путь к папке библиотек:

```
-L__ВАШ_ПУТЬ_К_MINGW__\i686-w64-mingw32\lib
```

Кстати, советую скачать свежий mingw-w64 и заменить в опциях Нетбинса пути для его использования вместо того старого, который идет с ним в комплекте.

Comment: Спасибо, я в комментариях к посту уже писал, как решил проблему.